# How to append text to HTML input form?

Tags: html, forms

I have created a basic html input form, but would like to append some text to the users input, how would I do that?

```
<form action="https://api.hipchat.com/v1/rooms/message" method="get" target="">
  <input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="color" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="example">

  Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to get some input from the user, then post it to a HipChat room. All of it works as it is. But I would like to add "@Lewis" for example before the message so I receive a mention on HipChat. Is it possible to do something like:

value="@Lewis" + "Submit"

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to submit the form? You would need to use that to append data

Comment: I'm just using a basic HTML page with a button. Is that what you mean? @codedude

Comment: That'll be tough using just html. You could always use a hidden field for it, but it needs to be parsed on the receiving end. Another option is JavaScript..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to add jQuery for this request. A small JavaScript will serve you just as good, and be much more lightweight. But if you plan on using a lot of js you might want to start checking out jQuery.

```html
<form id="myForm" action="https://api.hipchat.com/v1/rooms/message" method="get" target="">
  <input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="color" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="example">Message:
  <input type="text" name="message" id="myMessage">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
      var msgElement = document.getElementById("myMessage");
      msgElement.value = '@Lewis: ' + msgElement.value;
      alert(msgElement.value); //comment/remove this line
      return true;
    };
  };
</script>
```

Notice that I added **id** to the form and message element.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It will only be a basic form, so JavaScript  should suffice. Although I am still a little stuck, even after putting in the form id, it still doesn't seem to add it to the URL. Which is strange considering the alert works? Do I need to change 'myMessage'? Edit: Just sen the id field on message, changing that now!

Comment: @Lewis I've added an Id to both the form and the message input. Both must exist, as they are used to find the elements by the javascript.

Comment: That works really well, thanks! One final question though, how could I make it so the submit button doesn't open a new page? It takes me to an ugly HipChat page confirming the message has been sent. I'd prefer a JavaScript popup or something to prevent the page from changing. I tried changing target to an iframe, but that still seems to open a new page?

Comment: @Lewis Nothing in your code (that you posted) is causing the new window popup, so it must be the receiver of the post. You could send it using **ajax** instead (silently, without a redirect), but you'll either have to ask a new question about that or search SO/google (plenty of questions and guides around on that) since it's not in the scope of your current question. Glad that it works for you though.

Comment: yes, I agree. it's best to not use jQuery if this is the only thing that you're going to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I just want to chime in and say that javascript seems to be the solution for so many of these little problems. where simple form tags could suffice. Imagine if you could combine a prefix and suffix to a text field in html.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JavaScript. Add a submit handler and prepend the text you want to the start of the message. An example using jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
      var $m = $(this).find('[name=message]');
      $m.val('@Lewis ' + $m.val();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm beginner at this, how do I add a submit handler? How would I incorporate the jQuery into the form?

Comment: The only thing you need to do to get this to work is include the jQuery library and put the above code in a script tag. That's all. I adjusted the code so you can copy and paste it into your page